# Highlight Corresponding Names With Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, colors, prompt

I have a list of names to display in a browser:

> Alan, Ben, Cindy, Dan, Ellen, Fred.

I'd like the user to be able to select *male* or *female*.
Then I'd like the name(s) of people who are that gender to change colors, or become highlighted.

Is there a way to do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, you can do following:

```
// step 1 create list of names with classes
<ul>
  <li class="person male">Alan</li>
  <li class="person male">Ben</li>
  <li class="person female">Cindy</li>
</ul>

// step 2 create dropdown list of genders
<select id="my-dropdown-id" name="gender">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>

// step 3 simple jQuery script
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#my-dropdown-id').change(function() {      
    $('.person').removeClass('selected');
    $('.' + this.value).addClass('selected');
  });
</script>

<style>
  .selected{
    background: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

This is a very simple solution, though i believe it implements your idea at least theoretically.

Comment: `I'd like the user to be able to select male or female.`

Comment: I added the `style` tag for you.